# Android Coffee Shop

Tags: android

So for my App Dev class i had to make an app for a coffee shop. It must have two checkboxes for whipped cream and chocolate. It must accept a user's name, allow them to check the respective checkboxes, add a quantity of their product, and display a bill with their total. For some reason, the 0 in between the minus and plus buttons will not change when the buttons are pressed, and the bottom text below the order button will not display the relevant information.

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.chan.coffeeshop;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int quantity = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void decrementQuantity(View view) {
        quantity = quantity - 1;
        if (quantity < 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Less than 1 is not valid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            displayquantity(quantity);
        }
    }

    public void incrementQuantity(View view) {
        quantity = quantity + 1;
        if (quantity > 10) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "More than 10 is not valid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            displayquantity(quantity);
        }
    }

    private void displayquantity(int quantity) {
        TextView quantity1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product_Quantity);
        quantity1.setText("" + quantity);
    }

    public void OrderButton(View view) {

        EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);

        String names = name.getText().toString();
        CheckBox choc = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chocolate);
        Boolean chocs = choc.isChecked();
        CheckBox whippedCream = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.whipped_Cream);
        Boolean whipped = whippedCream.isChecked();
        int price = calculatePrice(chocs, whipped);
        String finalMessage = createFinalMessage(names, chocs, whipped, price);
        displayMessage(finalMessage);
    }

    private void displayMessage(String finalMessage) {
        TextView Message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bill_Total);
        Message.setText("" + finalMessage);
    }

    private String createFinalMessage(String names, Boolean chocs, Boolean whipped, int price) {
        String Message = "Name: " + names + "\n" + "chocolate ordered: " + chocs + "\n" + "whipped cream ordered: " + whipped + "\n" + "Total Price: " + price;
        return Message;
    }

    private int calculatePrice(Boolean chocs, Boolean whipped) {

        int price = 5;
        if (chocs)
        {
            price = price + 1;
        }
        if (whipped)
        {
            price = price + 1;
        }
        return price * quantity;
    }
}
```

Here is the layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="64dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    tools:context="com.example.chan.coffeeshop.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/welcome"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="76dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Welcome to Chandler's Coffee Shop App!"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="5dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-8dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Buy some high quality coffee for only 5 bucks!"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-17dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="88dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="66dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="24dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="134dp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/whipped_Cream"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Whipped Cream $1"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="39dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="211dp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chocolate"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="375dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Chocolate $1"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="225dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="211dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/coffee_Quantity"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Quantity"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="153dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="263dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="83dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.53">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/minus_Button"
                android:layout_width="156dp"
                android:layout_height="72dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="-"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="39dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="306dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/product_Quantity"
                android:layout_width="44dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="186dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="330dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/plus_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="72dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="+"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="240dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="306dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/coffee_Price"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Price"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="172dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="388dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/coffee_Order"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="ORDER"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="91dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="423dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="6dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bill_Total"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="27dp"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="45dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="485dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What *exactly* is the problem you are having ("won't work" tells us nothing) , and what have you already tried yourself to find the problem? Questions should show **evidence of research and attempts to solve the problem yourself**, a clear outline of the specific issue, and the *relevant code* in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we have enough information to be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

I checked your code and found out that neither an `onClick` nor an `onClickListener` is set to the buttons. 
How will they suppose to work then?

**Either:**
set onClick in XML like
`android:onClick="decrementQuantity"` for `minus_Button`
`android:onClick="decrementQuantity"` for `plus_Button`
`android:onClick="OrderButton"` for `coffee_Order`

**Or:**
set `onClickListener` on the buttons in onCreate like

```
        Button plusButton = findViewById(R.id.plus_button);
        Button minusButton = findViewById(R.id.minus_Button);
        Button orderButton = findViewById(R.id.coffee_Order);
        plusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                incrementQuantity(view);
            }
        });    
        minusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                decrementQuantity(view);
             }
        });
         orderButton .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                OrderButton(view);
             }
        });
```

Possibly, these are the only wrong things in your code, try this.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set OnClickListeners for your buttons.  Once you do that, it should work, your increment and decrement functions look ok.  You'll also need to set the total in them if you want it to update.

Answer (score 0):

In the Layor design view double click minus/plus button to add your incrementQuantity/decrementQuantity
and also neet to set onClickListener as a trigger to active your button.

If you want to display the quantity on the view, you also need to pass your quantity to a variable to display on the UI level